# ID for subgraph with delayed Arangodb write

Tags: graph, arangodb

I am building a web application where users are creating graph data. 
This data is stored in arangodb after a while, 
after several documents and relations between new and existing documents have been created in the application.

What would be the best way to handle the creation of key/id in that case?

Can I rely on some client-side ID generation algorithm ( any recommended?) 
or is it possible to 'book' a set of generated keys from ArangoDB before the creation of those new documents/relations on the client?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate collection in ArangoDB; 
You save document into it and fetch the id afterwards.

You could also write a [simple Foxx service doing that for you](https://docs.arangodb.com/Foxx/index.html)

Otoh, [there are reliable client side id generators available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320568/best-way-to-generate-unique-ids-client-side-with-javascript)